# How to repeat animations in a collectionView or tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios-animations

The simplified version of my problem is I am trying to loop/repeat an animation on a button within collectionView cells, but the animation only is executed once.  This is my animation block located within my collectionViewCell:

```
func animateGlowingCircle() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        self.glowCircle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tried calling the animateGlowingCircle() from several different places: within the collectionViewController's viewDidLoad or cellForRowAt, as well as from the collectionView's draw.  The closest I can get is the animation only executes once but it doesn't loop.  I've found tons of info online regarding single-executed animations, but nothing for looped.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:  the looping cell animation needs to be called from the collectionViewController's **willDisplayCell** method.  So something like this:

```
// In collectionViewController    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let timerCell = cell as! TimerCollectionViewCell
    timerCell.animateGlowingCircle()  
}


// In collectionViewCell (this is the same code posted with the question)
func animateGlowingCircle() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        self.glowCircle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: and? Cell is reused so you may run multiple animations for the same cell